# Should I execute every query or single query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm trying to Insert multiple records to table using `ado.net`, and print `id` inserted.

My code is like this:

```
List<string> listQuery = new List<string>()
{
    "INSERT INTO Students (Name) VALUES ('student1');SELECT @@Identity;",
    "INSERT INTO Students (Name) VALUES ('student2');SELECT @@Identity;",
    "INSERT INTO Students (Name) VALUES ('student3');SELECT @@Identity;",
};
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = connection;

            foreach (var myQuery in listQuery)
            {
                command.CommandText = myQuery;
                int id = Convert.ToInt32((decimal)command.ExecuteScalar());
                Console.WriteLine("Inserted: " + id);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        //Close and dispose
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

I wondering, whether should I execute every command like that? Or concatenate all query and execute just a times?.

If I should execute one times. How can i get all `id` of records inserted?

Comment: you can perform the `INSERT` for multiple rows in one go and return the `id` using `OUTPUT` clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause to return the identity `id`

```
INSERT INTO Students (Name)
OUTPUT  INSERTED.id
VALUES ('student1'), ('student2'), ('student3');
```

Comment: Or `OUTPUT INSERTED.id, INSERTED.Name` to get something you can map to the source.

Comment: Please write some code to get all id. If i use `OUTPUT` clause, i need to use `ExecuteReader`. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Don't go like this, and DON'T call database in ANY loop.

For resolving your problem, you should write stored procedure that take a DataTable as input of your student list ([tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/bb675163(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)) or use [JSON string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) as input. In that stored procedure you use `OUTPUT` clause to retrieve id: `OUTPUT INSERTED.id` . On C# code, you only need `ExecuteReader` to get all id.

Comment: While I tend to agree with your sentiment, it would be much better if you could show some code that explains how to go about doing this.